# OpenCover 4.7.1221 Size of the xml output file more then OpenCover 4.6.166

Tags: opencover

I am just checking by executing single test case for Mstest framework for Dotnet 4.6 based assembly test case. It is generating more size compared to 4.6.166 version

`C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\opencover\4.7.1221\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe  -register:path32 -output:"D:\..\..\OpenCoverTest\RunOpenCover\test.xml" -target:"C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\microsoft.testplatform\17.1.0\tools\net451\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe" -targetargs:"D:\..\..\..OpenCoverageTest.dll /Tests:RunOpenCover" -filter:"" -excludebyattribute:*.ExcludeFromCodeCoverage*`

For 4.6.166 file size is only 52kb and
for 4.7.1221 file size is 124kb.

Let me know if you have any idea. Thanks in advance.